# SharePoint masterpage to .wsp solution

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Created SharePoint Master page and css deploying manually uploading process ...I want to make that master page and css to .wsp Solution package feature ? i am not a developer

Comment: Do you have access to visual studio? What version of SharePoint is it?

Comment: yes visual studio has install in my system..we are in SharePoint 2010 version!!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg447066%28v=office.14%29.aspx) tutorial will walk you through creating a custom branding solution. Branding is what custom CSS and MasterPages are generally referred to.

A summary of the process is to:

1. Create an empty SharePoint project in Visual Studio.
2. Add a Module that deploys to the master page gallery for your master
   page.
3. Add a Module that deploys to the Style Libary for your css.
4. Add your Master Page and Css to the project in their respective
   folders.
5. Package the wsp
6. Deploy to the farm

Remember you must have SharePoint installed on the machine you have visual studio on for this to work. Unfortunatly, remote development was not added until 2013.